# Complile ane with ant

Tags: android, ant, air, air-native-extension

I`m trying to compile my ane with ant, but have message:

```
[java] Missing implementation for platform: Android-ARM
```

Ant file:

```
<property name="FLEX_HOME" value="C:/Program Files (x86)/FlexSDK/4.11.0/"/> 

<target name="compile.ane">
    <java jar="${FLEX_HOME}/lib/adt.jar" fork="true">
        <arg value="-package"/>
        <arg value="-target"/>
        <arg value="ane"/>
        <arg value="commExtension.ane"/>
        <arg value="extension.xml"/>
        <arg value="-swc"/>
        <arg value="commExtLib.swc"/>
        <arg value="-platform Android-ARM -C android/ ."/>
        <arg value="-platform default -C default/ ."/>
    </java>
</target>
```

But if i comlile it with command line, it`s ok.

```
adt -package -target ane commExtension.ane extension.xml -swc commExtLib.swc -platform     Android-ARM -C android . -platform default -C default
```

What i`m doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
<target name="compile.ane">
     <exec executable="${FLEX_HOME}/bin/adt.bat">
          <arg value="-package"/>
          <arg value="-target"/>
          <arg value="ane"/>
          <arg value="commExtension.ane"/>
          <arg value="extension.xml"/>
          <arg line="-swc"/>
          <arg line="commExtLib.swc"/>
          <arg line="-platform Android-ARM -C android/ ."/>
     </exec>
</target>
```